# Erro de relacionamento e método não encontrado

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

estou estudando Laravel e tenho dificuldades para realizar o relacionamento de uma tabela associativa que liga 3 tabelas de dominio.
exemplo do meu modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema e que não consigo mapear a partir da minha comanda a outras entidades.
Segue o meu código:

**Model da Comanda:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comanda extends Model
{

    public function mesas(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Mesa');
    }
    public function garcom(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Garcom');
    }


}
```

**Modelo do Garçom:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Garcom extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'setor'];
}
```

**Modelo da Mesa:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Mesa extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['setor'];

    public function garcoms(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Garcom')->withtimestamps();
    }
    public function produtos(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Produto')->withtimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Modelo do Produto:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produto extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome', 'valor'];
}
```

**Pra testar tudo isso, utilizei o artisan tinker e digitei o seguinte:**

```
$comanda = App\Comanda::first()
$comanda->mesas()
```

**Porem tive o seguinte erro como retorno:**

```
  BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mesas()'
```

Nesse ponto não sei por que o objeto comanda não encontra o metodo mesa, tão pouco se esse mapeamento que fiz está correto.
Vocês poderiam me ajudar nisso ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu model de Comanda você deve indicar o id do seu campo no segundo paramêtro do relacionamento como abaixo:

```
public function mesas(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Mesa', 'mesa_id');
}
```

Isto deve funcionar

--

Edit 2:
O erro de método undefinied eu tentaria sem os parênteses '()' em mesas()

Comment: Solucionado. Muito obrigado !

Comment: Eu quem agradeço. Nesse caso peço para que marque minha resposta como válida